# Contact Summary Layout based on relationship

Tags: relationships, contact-summary-editor

There is an extension called "Contact Summary Editor" by colemanmw which enables users to see specific parts of contact based on the group the user belongs to. During editing you can enable which ACL group is able to see which Contact Summary Layout.

I am wondering if there is a way to overwrite this extension to be able to choose which relationship enables certain Contact Summary Layout. For example, if the user is the relationship with the "Contact A" and this relationship is called "Owner of", then the user can see the most informations regarding "Contact A" and so on.

Have any one stumbled upon Contact views based on relationships?

Comment: This is a great feature request.  I've actually received a very similar request, but I actually need to more conclusively block the data from appearing *anywhere* - e.g. searches and reports, not just the contact summary page.  It's proven to be pretty tough.  I think modifying the contact summary layout extension is an easier job.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a Smart group for each relationship type or so and having the layout available to group of contact. If not using [Apiwrapper](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_apiWrappers) hook you can alter the filters of 'ContactLayout' entity.

Comment: Okay, but what about if:

User A is owner of Contact A but not of the Contact B.
As the owner, User A is added to the smart group "Owners" - and users in this group have Contact Layout.

But then he could just go to the Contact B and still see the "owner layout" is that correct? Even though he is not the owner of Contact B

Comment: No, it's not what I'am looking for - Contact Summary Editor is not compatibile with smart groups and I want to be able to limit layout per contact not per group.

Comment: I meant to add Contact A in smart group but it will still show the screen if Contact B is owned by someone else.. Contact layout does support smart groups

Comment: You can also use hook to alter the condition

Comment: I don't know how to use ApiWrapper or hooks correctly. I will try once again with the smart groups

Comment: Contact Layout Editor sees smart groups (when choosing groups) but after saving the layout the extensions says the layout is avaliable to all users -> https://i.imgur.com/GTTC00E.png

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Permissioned Relationship](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension to provide the control over contact A seeing Contact B but not Contact C. And then also add Contact A (and all similar contacts) in to a Group and use that Group and Contact Layout to control what they actually see on the Contacts Summary screen